# How can i store raw data into a PNG file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, python-requests, binaryfiles

```
>>> def qrcodegenerate(nbr):
...     res = requests.get("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x330&choe=UTF-8&chl="+str(nbr))
...     print(res.url)
...     data =res.text
...     with open("C:\wamp\www\Paymentapi\qrcode\qr_"+str(nbr)+'.png','w',encoding="utf-8") as f:
...             f.write(data)
...
>>> qrcodegenerate(5697)
```

Here I am calling API to generate a QR code and I want to save into a PNG file.

The QR code is being generated, but it's not being saved correctly.

Answer (score 3):

PNG files contain binary data, not UTF-8 text.

What you need to do is:

1. Use [`res.content`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) (binary) instead of [`res.text`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content) (text).
2. [Open the file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) in binary mode (`wb`) instead of text mode (`w`), without specifying an encoding.

The resulting code should look like this:

```
def qrcodegenerate(nbr):
    res = requests.get('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x330&choe=UTF-8&chl=' + str(nbr))
    print(res.url)
    data = res.content
    with open('...', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)
```

Comment: thanks alot  @Andrea Corbellini . Its working fine and also thnks for explaining my mistake.